# How to fix this error "fromarray" function from PIL module python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I just try to learn how to create image from array with replit.com

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
emtpy=np.zeros((24,24))
emtpy[:,:]=[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
print(emtpy)
img=Image.fromarray(emtpy, "1")
img.save("test.png")
```

This is what i got:
[image: ![enter image description here]
(it's 24x24 matrix)

And the image:
[image]

**why they seem not similar to the array?**

I already try another mode of fromarray,by change "1" to "L" and other, they still not work
[image]
("L" mode)

My expectation is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your data you'll see it is `float`, because it has a decimal point.

You need an unsigned 8-bit integer:

```
emtpy=np.zeros((24,24), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then, when you create an `Image` object you will need to do this to be in the correct range for 8-bit pixels, i.e. 0..255:

```
img=Image.fromarray(emtpy*255, "L")
```

Comment: that still not working.it return the black image

Comment: Sorry, I missed the other error first time :-)